# Drupal modules for ticketing system

Tags: drupal

We are looking at implementing a ticketing system at our work place. We intially tried OS Ticket which was fine. But management are hoping to integrate it into out intranet. (which will be done in Drupal) The Ticketing system will be used for the IT Team.

Are there any modules available in Drupal that handle tickets or a module that can implement a ticketing system into Drupal.

Any suggestions or experience in this area will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

http://drupal.org/project/support

Answer (score 2):

Check out [OpenAtrium](http://openatrium.com/). It's a Drupal distribution aimed at corporate intranets. They have tied together a bunch of Drupal contrib modules into a very well-integrated project management/bug tracking/wiki system. You may not want to implement OpenAtrium as your whole intranet, but it would likely be helpful for you to install it so you can look under the hood to see what modules they've used and how they're tied together.